# Handle missing key from dict

Tags: python, json

I have this script which I use to pull in some data from an API call.

```
# list of each api url to use
link =[]
#for every device id , create a new url link into the link list
for i in deviceIDList:
    link.append('https://website/v2/accounts/accountid/devices/'+i)

#create a list with all the different requests

deviceReq = []
for i in link:
    deviceReq.append(requests.get(i, headers=headers).json())


# write to a txt file
with open('masterSheet.txt', 'x') as f:
    for i in deviceReq:
        devices =[i['data']]
        for x in devices:
            models = [x['provision']]
            for data in models:
              sheet=(data['endpoint_model']+" ",x['name'])
              f.write(str(sheet)+"\n")
```

Some devices do not have the `provision` key.

Here is some sample data looks like from a device that is different.

Let's say I want to grab the `device_type` key value instead if `provision` key is non-existent.

```
"data": {
        "sip": {
            "username": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "expire_seconds": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
            "invite_format": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "method": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "route": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },

        "device_type": "msteams",
        "enabled": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        "suppress_unregister_notifications": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        "owner_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    }
```

**How do I cater for missing keys?**

Comment: use `dict.get()` like this `x.get('provision', x.get('device_type'))`

Comment: Can you post full example ?

Comment: That is a full example. If `x['provision']` throws a KeyError, then `x.get('provision')` will not and instead return None. The second parameter is the default if the key does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.get(key, defualt_value)` to get the value from a dict, or if one is not present it will use the default like this:

```py
provision = x.get('provision', None)
if provision is None:
    provision = x.get('device_type')
models = [provision]
```

or if you prefer you can do the same on one line and without the extra if or assignment (though some people might find it more difficult to read and understand.

```py
models = [x.get('provision', x.get('device_type'))]
```

Comment: Thanks - I will try this and let you know how it goes

Comment: Ah `endpoint_model` is a nested key within `provision` . let's provision does not exist then endpoint model will not exist either. How do I cater for that?

Comment: reason I'm asking is it throws this error ` sheet=(data['endpoint_model']+" ",data['name'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable `

Comment: Didn't see your comment earlier, sorry. If you need to access a lower level of the dictionary I would go with the `if...else` syntax for readability. E.g. `if provision is None: ... else: data = provision.get("endpoint_model")...`. My general recommendation is to always use `if` and `.get("field", default)`, don't worry about having too many nested levels or efficiency until it becomes a problem, then optimise as the last step.